# HTTP Status Check with Zabbix Agent Active Mode

Tags: zabbix

I have a `Zabbix Agent` running protected by a firewall in intranet and `Zabbix Server` installed in `Digital Ocean` (Internet). `Zabbix Server` can't communicate to `Zabbix Agent` because of the firewall, but the Agent can send data to Server, so i need to use only "Active Checks" and avoid "Passive Checks".

I have a `JBOSS` running in same HOST that `Zabbix Agent` (Under Firewall) is, and I need to check if the application is running under port `8084`, usually (without firewall protection) I would create a Web Scenario with `HTTP 200` check but I can't do it because Server can't reach application inside intranet.

I need some solution to check application under `Zabbix Agent` with "Active Mode".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the exact need, you can use `net.tcp.listen`, `net.tcp.port`, `net.tcp.service` or `web.page.get` [agent item](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent).

Note that `web.page.get` is quite rudimentary and does not support chunked encoding, for example - that results in unexpected data inserted in the returned page.